# Sharepoint 2013 online custom folder limit

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, folder

Got a noob question regarding folders in a document library.  I want to limit the amount of folders a user can create inside a document library.  Is there a way to do this as I can only find the option to turn on/off folder creation?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to create Remote event receiver for that.

Comment: I dont think there is simply a way to do it OOB. However you can create event receivers to resolve this issue.

Comment: I see. So create event receiver which sets a limit to row size! or something like that.  Ok thanks guys.